# Cómo hacer cálculo con $http AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, http

Tengo un problema con un ejercicio que estoy haciendo. Se trata de que tengo un formulario donde tengo que añadir la cantidad € y los plazos en los que quiero pagar el préstamo. La parte del formulario y su cálculo con el boton NG-enviar está hecho, incluso que cuando clico el boton me muestre el resultado pero sin las soluciones.
Exactamente mi problema es que no se como hacer para que cuando le de al boton me salga el resultado con todo calculado.

Mi HTML es este:

```
<div class="jumbotron" background-color="#FFF8DC">
        <div style="position:center ; color: #1D66EE">
            <h1>//ABANCA</h1>
        </div>
        <p class="lead">
            Préstamos en 24H. Haz tus cuentas.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formAppCtrl">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="http://localhost:58498/api/Cuota" class="form-horizontal" method="get" role="form" id="formulario-cuotas">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="Cuotas">¿Cuánto quieres pedir?</label>
                    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-cuotas="El campo de las Cuotas está vacío. No es válido" data-val-required="El campo Cuotas es obligatorio." id="Cuotas" name="cantidad" type="number" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text--danger" data-valmsg-for="Cuotas" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
                <p>
                    "Con el préstamo 24h puedes pedir a partir
                    <br> de 500€, pero para cantidades de hasta 3000€
                    <br> tiene que ser en la "<a href="/es/tarjetas/tarjetas-credito/tarjeta-visa-clip" target="_blank">
                        modalidad de
                        tarjeta <br>
                    </a> ".Por eso este simulador empieza en 3000€ que
                    <br> es lo mínimo que puedes pedir en la modalidad
                    <br> de préstamo. Ten en cuenta que no puedes
                    <br> solicitar más de lo que cuesta lo que vayas
                    <br> financiar."
                </p>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Plazo" class="control-label">¿Cuándo deseas devolverlo?</label>
                    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-cuotas="El campo de los plazos está vacío. No es válido" data-val-required="El campo Plazos es obligatorio." id="Plazos" name="plazos" type="text" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text--danger" data-valmsg-for="Plazos" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
                <p>
                    "Puedes devolverlo en un plazo maximo de 96 meses,
                    <br> osea, 8 años"
                </p>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="tipo" id="optionsRadios1" value="hipotecario" checked="">
                        <font>
                            <font class="">
                                Crédito Hipotecario.
                            </font>
                        </font>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="tipo" id="optionsRadios2" value="personal" checked="">
                        <font>
                            <font class="">
                                Crédito Personal.
                            </font>
                        </font>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
            </form>
            <button id="btnenviar" name="btnenviar" class="btn btn-primary input-group">
                ENVIAR
            </button>
            <br>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button ng-click="myForm()">
                        NG-ENVIAR
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div ng-show="showMe">
                <form method="get" action="http://localhost:58498" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="respuestaform">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <h3>Resultado:</h3>
                    <div id="resultado"></div>
                    <h4>Cantidad</h4>
                    <div id="contenedor-cantidad">{{respuesta.cantidad}}</div>
                    <h4>Cuota</h4>
                    <div id="contenedor-cuota">{{respuesta.cuota}}</div>
                    <h4>Plazos</h4>
                    <div id="contenedor-plazos">{{respuesta.plazos}}</div>
                    <h4>Tipo</h4>
                    <div id="tipo">{{respuesta.tipo}}</div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

=================================================

Este es el Script que tengo:

```
angular.module('formApp', [])
.controller('formAppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    var logresultado = function(cantidad, cuota, plazos, tipo) {
        return cantidad + "contenedor-cuota" + cuota + "contenedor-plazos" + plazos + "contenedor-tipo" + tipo
    };

    $scope.myForm = function() {
        $http.get().success(function(cantidad, cuota, plazos, tipo) {

            $scope.myForm = logresultado("GET", cantidad, cuota, plazos, tipo);
        })
    }

    $scope.showMe = false;
    $scope.myForm = function() {
        console.log('entra aqui')
        $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe
    };
});
```

==================================

Y en una clase del controlador hago la operacion que eso me va bien pero os lo dejo por si lo necesitais:

```js
angular.module('formApp', [])
.controller('formAppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    var logresultado = function (cantidad, cuota, plazos, tipo) {
        return cantidad + "contenedor-cuota" + cuota + "contenedor-plazos" + plazos + "contenedor-tipo" + tipo
    };

    $scope.myForm = function () {
        $http.get().success(function (cantidad, cuota, plazos, tipo) {

            $scope.myForm = logresultado("GET", cantidad, cuota, plazos, tipo);
        })
    }

    $scope.showMe = false;
    $scope.myForm = function () {
       console.log('entra aqui')
       $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe
    };
});
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron" background-color="#FFF8DC">
    <div style="position:center ; color: #1D66EE">
        <h1>//ABANCA</h1>
    </div>

    <p class="lead">
        Préstamos en 24H.
        Haz tus cuentas.
    </p>

</div>

<div class="row" ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formAppCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <form action="http://localhost:58498/api/Cuota" class="form-horizontal"
              method="get" role="form" id="formulario-cuotas">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="Cuotas">¿Cuánto quieres pedir?</label>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true"
                       data-val-cuotas="El campo de las Cuotas está vacío. No es válido"
                       data-val-required="El campo Cuotas es obligatorio." id="Cuotas"
                       name="cantidad" type="number" value="">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text--danger"
                      data-valmsg-for="Cuotas" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>

            <p>
                "Con el préstamo 24h puedes pedir a partir <br>
                de 500€, pero para cantidades de hasta 3000€ <br>
                tiene que ser en la "<a href="/es/tarjetas/tarjetas-credito/tarjeta-visa-clip" target="_blank">
                    modalidad de
                    tarjeta <br>
                </a>
                ".Por eso este simulador empieza en 3000€ que <br>
                es lo mínimo que puedes pedir en la modalidad <br>
                de préstamo. Ten en cuenta que no puedes <br>
                solicitar más de lo que cuesta lo que vayas <br>
                financiar."
            </p>


            <br>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Plazo" class="control-label">¿Cuándo deseas devolverlo?</label>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true"
                       data-val-cuotas="El campo de los plazos está vacío. No es válido"
                       data-val-required="El campo Plazos es obligatorio." id="Plazos"
                       name="plazos" type="text" value="">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text--danger"
                      data-valmsg-for="Plazos" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>

            <p>
                "Puedes devolverlo en un plazo maximo de 96 meses,<br>
                osea, 8 años"
            </p>

            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="tipo" id="optionsRadios1" value="hipotecario" checked=""><font>
                        <font class="">
                            Crédito Hipotecario.
                        </font>
                    </font>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="tipo" id="optionsRadios2" value="personal" checked=""><font>
                        <font class="">
                            Crédito Personal.
                        </font>
                    </font>
                </label>
            </div>

            <br>
            <br>


        </form>

        <button id="btnenviar" name="btnenviar" class="btn btn-primary input-group">
            ENVIAR
        </button>
        <br>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button ng-click="myForm()">
                    NG-ENVIAR
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div ng-show="showMe">
            <form method="get" action="http://localhost:58498" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="respuestaform">
               
                <br>
                <br><h3>Resultado:</h3>

                <div id="resultado"></div>

                <h4>Cantidad</h4>
                <div id="contenedor-cantidad">{{respuesta.cantidad}}</div>

                <h4>Cuota</h4>
                <div id="contenedor-cuota">{{respuesta.cuota}}</div>

                <h4>Plazos</h4>
                <div id="contenedor-plazos">{{respuesta.plazos}}</div>

                <h4>Tipo</h4>
                <div id="tipo">{{respuesta.tipo}}</div>

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Silvia! por que tienes dos funciones llamadas `$scope.myForm`

Comment: el $scope.myForm que tengo es para hacer relevancia al boton cuando clico.

Comment: solo tengo una funcion myForm y es la del boton

Comment: Me pasa que no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres lograr, tu llamas a una clase, que esta clase llama a una API que te devuelve los valores cierto?

Comment: Si exacto! en cuanto le doy al boton enviar me aparece un formulario con cantidad, cuota etc...lo que yo quiero esque me salga el resultado de cada uno. Perdona si no souy muy clara pero me cuesta explicarme. Sorry!

Comment: quieres ver que se ingreso en cada uno de esos campos y no el resultado del calculo?

Comment: El resultado del calculo tendria que salir en cada uno de esos campos: cantidad(lo que pido en el prestamo), cuota(resultado del la division entre cantidad y plazos), plazos(los meses que he elegido), tipo(el tipo de prestamo). Solo me falta eso, que me salga el resultado en cada uno de esos campos. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Yo me imagino que el usuario ingresa la Cantidad, Las cuotas, el plazo y el tipo de prestamo. Y en base a estos valores tu obtienes un resultado que seria El valor de la cuota, etc etc?

Comment: Si, exactamente

Comment: Ok, me queda un poco más claro!

Comment: En la pantalla me aparece el formulario con el boton, y cuando le doy al boton me sale a la derecha el formulario con los campos que te dije pero sin sus respectivos resultados. Lo digo por si lo ves mejor asi jeje. Gracias :)

Comment: Una ultima consulta tu no puedes ver tu div `<div ng-show="showMe">` porque ese valor `showMe` no cambia verdad? Porque el calculo efectivamente si se hace correctamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo veo que por lo cual no se muestra tu div es por la siguiente razon

```
$scope.myForm = function() {
    $http.get().success(function(cantidad, cuota, plazos, tipo) {

        $scope.myForm = logresultado("GET", cantidad, cuota, plazos, tipo);
    })
}

$scope.showMe = false;
$scope.myForm = function() {
    console.log('entra aqui')
    $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe
};
```

Cuando tu boton hace click llama a la funcion `$scope.myForm` de las cuales hay 2 referencias...., entra siempre a la ultima el que imprime "Entra aqui".
Para que puedas ver bien el resultado tienes que hacer lo siguiente

```
angular.module('formApp', [])
.controller('formAppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.contenedor = {};
    $scope.contenedor.cantidad = "";
    $scope.contenedor.cuota = "";
    $scope.contenedor.plazos = "";
    $scope.contenedor.tipo = "";
    var logresultado = function(cantidad, cuota, plazos, tipo) {
        $scope.contenedor.cantidad = cantidad;
        $scope.contenedor.cuota = cuota;
        $scope.contenedor.plazos = plazos
        $scope.contenedor.tipo = tipo;
    };

    $scope.myForm = function() {
        $http.get().success(function(cantidad, cuota, plazos, tipo) {

            logresultado("GET", cantidad, cuota, plazos, tipo);
            mostrarResultado();
        })
    }

    $scope.showMe = false;
    function mostrarResultado(){
      $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe;
    }
});
```

Y en tu HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div ng-show="showMe">
        <form method="get" action="http://localhost:58498" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="respuestaform">

            <br><h3>Resultado:</h3>

            <div id="resultado"></div>

            <h4>Cantidad</h4>
            <div >{{contenedor.cantidad}}</div>

            <h4>Cuota</h4>
            <div >{{contenedor.cuota}}</div>

            <h4>Plazos</h4>
            <div >{{contenedor.plazos}}</div>

            <h4>Tipo</h4>
            <div >{{contenedor.tipo}}</div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Puedes ver este pequeño ejemplo [aquí](http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/RGmbgK)

Por que te recomiendo cambiar tu codigo? Simple, AngularJS te ofrece manejar valores desde el controlador a la vista, viceversa y ver sus cambios de forma inmediata. De tal manera que en tu controlador :

- Click en el boton enviar y la funcion `myForm` llama a tu API
- Tu Api devuelve el calculo del credito
- Los resultados que tu API calculo, lo asignamos a un arreglo llamado `$scope.contenedor` y asignamos sus valores correspondientes
- Llamamos a la funcion encargada de cambiar el valor `false` por `true` de tu variable que condiciona la muestra del div de resultados
- Y AngularJS por debajo ya actualizo los valores.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! ya me va perfectamente

Comment: @SilviaGarcia excelente! Saludos!